# Regarding representation of Josephus puzzle using arrays

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm, josephus

Algorithms by Robert Sedwick, It was mentioned that linked list can be represented using Arrays, at following link

http://flylib.com/books/en/3.55.1.34/1/

Fig 3.8, here if 5 is removed from my understanding next 4 should be changed to index 6 as val 5 is removed, as we go thourgh the figure at item 4 is removed  next of val 3 is chaned. I am not following the logic of the figure. can aany one please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the index is zero-based as opposed to the value itself (letters would be better values).
Example of removing the value `5`: before removing, next index of the node with value `4` is 4, which points to value `5`; after removing, next index is changed to 5, pointing to value `6` (next changed from 4 to 5).

Or, using the prefix `v` to indicate values:

**before**

```
    index ...  3  4  5 ...
    ----------------------
    value     v4 v5 v6
    next       4  5  6
```

**after**

```
    index ...  3  4  5 ...
    ----------------------
    value     v4 v5 v6
    next       5  5  6
```

as you can see the node `v4` is followed by `v6` (index 5) practically removing `v5` from the chain.

Answer (score 0):

The values in the `next` array are the index of the next value in the chain. If you want to remove the value 5, which sits at index 4, you have to change `next[3]` from 4 to 5, so that the value at index 4 is effectively removed from the circle and will be skipped on later traversals.

[image: Josephus array implementation]

After the update highlighted, the "node" with a value of 4 points to the "node" with a value of 6.